# LibGDX websockets GWT html app cant find source to WebSocket class

Tags: libgdx, websocket, gradle

I'm using this library to connect to websocket server:
https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-lml/tree/master/websocket

It's working on android/desktop applications, but when compiling to html gwt app with **html:dist** command it returns many errors for websocket classes, this is one of them:

```
[ERROR] Line 25: No source code is available for type com.github.czyzby.websocket.WebSocket; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

I added all required libraries:

```
project(":core") {
   implementation "com.github.czyzby:gdx-websocket:1.9.1.9.6"
}

project(":html") {
   implementation "com.github.czyzby:gdx-websocket-gwt:1.9.1.9.6"
   implementation "com.github.czyzby:gdx-websocket-gwt:1.9.1.9.6:sources"
}
```

And in GdxDefinition.gwt.xml I added:

```
<inherits name='com.github.czyzby.websocket.GdxWebSocketGwt' />
```

But i don't know why I'm still getting this error with no source code available. Anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

**Solution:**
I downgraded websocket gwt library version in html module to

```
api 'com.github.czyzby:gdx-websocket-gwt:1.8.1.9.4'
api 'com.github.czyzby:gdx-websocket-gwt:1.8.1.9.4:sources'
```

And now it sees the source code for all websocket classes.

Comment: Please add details about versions of Gradle, LibGDX and Java to your question. Library you are using is [not maintained anymore](https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-lml/tree/master#disclaimer) so it may not work at all. You can check the forks they suggest, but I did not see any improvement there.

Comment: @Piro I'm using: Java 17 (17.0.4) gradle:7.2.2 and gdxVersion = '1.12.0'

Comment: One more thing that comes to mind is what gradle files are you changing? Only main gradle build file? Does html gradle build file also contain gwt dependencies?

Comment: I found the solition (added to main post). Thank you for the idea to reduce the version of the websocket gwt library :)

Comment: Hey, good you solved the issue. It is adviced to add your solution as an answer and then accept it so everybody knows this question is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** I downgraded websocket gwt library version in html module to

```
api 'com.github.czyzby:gdx-websocket-gwt:1.8.1.9.4'
api 'com.github.czyzby:gdx-websocket-gwt:1.8.1.9.4:sources'
```

And now it sees the source code for all websocket classes.